# Implementing business logic in Microsoft CRM

Tags: architecture, dynamics-crm, business-logic

We have been looking a several case studies that claim  vast improvements if you implement your Line-Of-Business applications in xRM.

Here is one such reference: http://www.webfortis.com/solutions/xRM%20Brochure.pdf

But xRM appears to be CRUD, workflow and presentation.

So my question is where would the business logic go in such a system? For example the calculation of a loan or approval of a credit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would expect your examples to be orchestrated by workflows.

A credit approval is a workflow with at least one step where the workflow halts until it gets feedback (approve/disapprove) from a human being and then eventually continues processing.

A loan calculation might be an external (or maybe internal) component which gets called from a workflow to do process input data and respond with output data.

(Disclaimer: I do not know MS Dynamics workflows in detail.)